# Attempting to restore Mail from Time Machine

Tags: backup, time-machine, mail.app, email

I asked this in a different form some time ago, but I'm trying to narrow down the situation.

I have a Time Machine backup of my previous computer.  On my current computer, I'm not in a position to restore the entire backup, so I'm trying to piecemeal this.

I used Time Machine to transfer over all of the files I thought were involved.  When I opened Mail, a dialog came up indicating it needed to import my mailboxes.  This took, like, 2 seconds, and then Mail appeared but none of my mailboxes were there.  Really none of my settings at all were there.

What, specifically, do I need to look for to copy over in order to have Mail be just like it was at my old station?

**Edit:**  Using File->Import Mailboxes, and selecting /Library/Mail, much (I'm still sorting) of my mail appears to have been dumped into an Import folder.  I'm disappointed my sidebar wasn't already full of my folder structure and importing my mail from my various accounts, but it's a start.  However...why isn't it importing my mail from my various accounts?  What's missing that it didn't, literally, pick up from where I left off?

The files I copied were (all ~user/):

- /Library/Application Support/Mail
- /Library/Mail
- /Library/Mail Downloads
- /Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail-shared.plist
- /Library/Preferences/com.apple.mail.plist